# How to fix System.UnauthorizedAccessException when decompressing bz2 file?

Tags: c#, permissions, sharpziplib

Im trying to decompress a bz2 file via code using the ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.

It seems no matter where I make my file, even though I have FULL ACCESS control over it, I keep getting this Exception. Any help greatly appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.IO;

using ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.BZip2;

namespace decompressor 
{ 
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string filePath = "C:\\FreeBase\\opinions.tsv.bz2";
            string decompressPath = "C:\\Users\\mike\\Desktop\\Decompressed";

            Console.WriteLine("Decompressing {0} to {1}", file, path);
             BZip2.Decompress(File.OpenRead(filePath),File.OpenWrite(decompressPath), true);                
        }       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code can have no access to create new paths at your desktop.
Check the permissions for the `"C:\\Users\\mike\\Desktop\\Decompressed"`.

Comment: Then why are you using this: `File.Create(path)`? Do your code have permissions for that file?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you should write so:

```
string decompressPath = "C:\\Users\\mike\\Desktop\\Decompressed\\opinions.tsv";
```